# Python 3.x : Jupyter Notebook and Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pcap

I have a got problem in my Pandas. I want to group my `pcap` file by `ip_src`, but it wasn't shown.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Anaconda\esktrak_uji_1.csv")
df

g = df.groupby('ip_src')
g
for ip_src, df.ip_src in g:
    print (ip_src)
    print (df.ip_src)
```

Jupyter Notebook image:

[image: result from scripts above]

[image: Output]

Comment: What does df look like?

Comment: result from df in image this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/v53Gn.jpg

Comment: Okay shows first few lines of your csv file.

Comment: here is the csv file https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlzkY.jpg

Comment: Okay, what do you want your output to look like?  Are you talking about sorting your df?  Or do you want count, sum, take the average of a particular column?

Comment: the csv file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzyl1ATtXuBhSFpWbmJCdkFmUjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yes i want to sort the df, take the average, count the average in the last 2s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for n,g in df.groupby('ip_src'):
    print(n)
    print(g)
```

To do a sort on df:

```
df.sort_values(by='ip_src')
```

Examples of some summary stats:

```
df.groupby('ip_src').agg({'no_paket':{'Sum':'sum'},'ip_dst':{'Count Distinct':'nunique'},'ttl':{'Mean':'mean'}})
```

Comment: is the data automatically renewed ?

Comment: Nope, you will have to create the dataframe by read_csv each time you want to update.

Comment: Thank Mr. Scott so much, it very helpfull. but why just ip_src == 192.168.1.5 has grouped ? how to group the others, the ip_src == 192.168.1.3 and the ip_src = 192.168.1.1

Comment: why the values of ip_src being the same as no_paket values ?